# How do I create an instance of a Class that is defined in Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, eval

The purpose of my code is to extract a string of code from some place, and later evaluate it. For example: If I have the following code:

```
foo(); a=b;
```

that appear in some file, I would like my code to execute it.
The file I am working on is a complex c# file, and only small part of it is relevant for the extraction and execution. First I run a regex on the file to find the relevant code snippet, and later I need to execute it.
My current solution (please advise) is to create a Reflection using CSharpCodeProvider. Obviously my code is then encapsulated by a namespace and  some class and a method. I later execute

```
   loCompiled = loCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(loParameters, codeToRun.ToString());
```

so I get the compiled code.
My questions are as follows:
1) what should I do next, after I compile this code?
2) Do you think there is a better way (technology wise) to implement what I need?

Comment: Have a look at scripting with Roslyn - https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples

Comment: The problem is that I cannot predict the content of the snippet I will have to evaluate. For example I have a method markedToEval in my file. and I will have to evaluate its whole contents with calls to other classes API, if statements, try catch and all that can be located inside a method.